# how to make native overlay diff false in docker overlay2?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, overlay

any idea how to make Native Overlay Diff config to false in docker? 
here is my docker info config,

```
docker info
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Supports d_type: true
Native Overlay Diff: true
```

just need to turn Native Overlay Diff:false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no active container there, you can use `modprobe -r overlay && modprobe overlay redirect_dir=on && systemctl restart docker` to make it false.

See [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt) and [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/36cd95dfa1ed76b59e2dcaafaa89c5479cec32b5/fs/overlayfs/Kconfig#L13) for more detail about this option.

Comment: It's really strange as it passed on my side: `# modprobe -r overlay && modprobe overlay redirect_dir=off && systemctl restart docker` and then `# docker info | grep "Native Overlay Diff"` returns `Native Overlay Diff: true`.
`# modprobe -r overlay && modprobe overlay redirect_dir=on && systemctl restart docker` and then `# docker info | grep "Native Overlay Diff"` returns `Native Overlay Diff: false`. Anyway, had to wait others to give you a solution.

Comment: I tried this on other system with docker and works. it's actually strange that doesn't work on other system :|

Comment: Ali this may depend on Linux kernel version.  I have read the docker source and it checks for a special file attribute to be set on a file.  My linux kernel creates that attribute despite the overlay module being configured to not support redirects.  So either it's a kernel bug or my expectations are incorrect.

Comment: @AlwynSchoeman any lead on that? I have the opposite situation where I want it true, but my kernel _4.19.65-1-MANJARO_ doesn't seem to cooperate. Even though I set _redirect_dir=off_ Docker still has Native Overlay Diff disabled. Would love some more feedback!!! Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCardoso, unfortunately no.  I spent more time working on my Ubuntu laptop where overlay2 works, so abandoned the investigation.